# Creating my first JSP, but Build.xml

Tags: eclipse, jsp, ant, jboss

I installed Eclipse Helios (Java EE IDE) and JBoss 6.0. I created a JSP file called Quote.JSP and put it under WebContent. I edited the Web.xml appropriately. But when I run the Ant build to produce the WAR file, I keep getting an error.

When I run it... I just can't get /quote/quote to come up. I'm at wits end and Googled answers until I can't take it anymore.

```
    <target name="war" depends="build">
  <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
  <war
    basedir="${webroot.dir}"
    warfile="${build.dir}/${project.distname}.war"
    webxml="${webinf.dir}/web.xml">
    <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/${build.dir}/**"/>
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/src/**"/>
    <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
   </war>
```

Any advice?

Comment: try remove this line `<fileset dir="WebContent"/>` and then run ant war again.

Comment: Tried, no go. I noticed this among the server problems: Description Resource Path Location Type
Classpath entry /quote/WebContent/quote.jsp will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result.   quote  P/quote Classpath Dependency Validator Message
 quote  P/quote Classpath Dependency Validator Message

Comment: your webroot.dir is ${basedir}/WebContent ?

Comment: Yes it is. It seems unorthodox based on a lot of the tutorials I read, but that's how Eclipse set it up...

Comment: when war is finished built, where should the quote.jsp exists?in <war_file>/quote/quote.jsp or <war_file>/quote.jsp?

Comment: According to the original tutorial, it should exist in /quote/quote.jsp. The structure goes... project name: quote, which opens to a bunch of libraries and WebContent, which in turn opens to META-INF, WEB-INF, and quote.jsp.

Comment: Let just say quote.jsp should be inside /quote/quote.jsp. quote.jsp should be reside in your eclipse WebContent -> quote directory (WebContent/quote/quote.jsp) and when you run ant war, the file will exists in quote_war/quote/quote.jsp. Period.

Comment: Let's see... JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1332190009812\deploy\quote.war\quote.jsp

Comment: ok, then that's odd. Perhaps you should update this question with your complete build.xml and your project directory setup in eclipse.

Comment: You got it. I'll hack away at it some more to make sure there's not something I missed. Thanks for your time, man!

Comment: ok, just update this question if you are still stuck, I can spend a little more time to take a look if you have updated your question with what I requested. By the way, our war target is the same, and it has been working fine here.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, it's probably not the build then. Maybe I should double check to see if I had to take another step to deploy it. But I thought that should do it.